# Nodes and Elements in the DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, element

Why are `Element` objects a subclass of `Node` objects? Aren't elements and nodes the same thing, with different names? Or are there other kinds of `Node`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Element`s are not the only node type.

- `Element` nodes are nodes that contain other nodes.
- `Text` nodes are nodes that contain text.
- `Attribute` nodes are nodes that contain attributes.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't even think that plain old text became nodes! Accepting when SO lets me...